# facebook page plugin displays only the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, plugins

The plugin just displays a link.I have tried writing http,https in js.src but nothing works,I also tried the code on local and hosting server but nothing works.Let me know if any changes needed in the code or any other plugin to get facebook page in the website.

```html
<body>
  
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts&amp;ref=br_tf" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">

  <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts&amp;ref=br_tf" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/betasportsclub/?fref=ts&amp;ref=br_tf">BETA Sports Club</a>

  </blockquote>
  
 </body>
```

Comment: This question is duplicate coz no one answered the previous one.

Comment: that does not mean you should ask the same question again in a different thread...